# python　実践データ分析100本ノック　ノック81に関して

Tags: python, opencv, jupyter-notebook

下記のコードを入力すると「NoneType object has no attribute “shape "」というエラーが表示されます。opencvは既にインストール済みで、画像もアップロード済みです。何か間違いがあればご指摘願いたいです。よろしくお願いします。

使用環境はジュピターノートブックです。

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread("img/img01.jpg")
height, width = img.shape[:2]
print("画像幅:"+str(width))
print("画像高さ:"+str(height))
cv2.imshow("img",img)
cv2.waitkey(0)
```

Comment: 本に関する質問自体は構わないのですが、タイトルは「何章について」等ではなく、あくまで **コードの内容やエラーメッセージ** に注目したものを心掛けてみてください。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。次回からご指摘のように質問することを心がけます。

Answer (score 0):

それはおそらくJupyterNotebookのカレントディレクトリの下に`img`ディレクトリか、さらにその下の`img01.jpg`ファイルが存在しないからでしょう。
例えばノートブックファイルの存在するディレクトリがカレントディレクトリになっているとは限りません。

それらが存在しなかったり、存在してもちゃんと読み込まれなかった場合は、`cv2.imread()`の戻り値が`None`になってその後の操作で質問のようなエラーになります。

こちらの記事などを参考に。
[【OpenCV】imreadでちゃんと読み込まれたか確認したいとき](https://qiita.com/musaprg/items/755d361b17ff77336474)

それからこちらの記事を参考に、カレントディレクトリの確認や移動を行ってみてください。
[Jupyter Notebookでのディレクトリ操作](https://qiita.com/mriho/items/42109231d25e7a0ce8c1)

> カレントディレクトリの取得は **%pwd** で行えます。

> カレントディレクトリの移動は **%cd** コマンドで行えます。

Comment: 何度も丁寧なご回答ありがとうございます。imgファイルのパスの指定位置が間違っていました。指定位置を変更したところ本の通りに表示できました